# How to display a custom value in an email sent by the Contact Form 7 plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, contact-form-7

I apologize in advance, but I don't speak English. This is a translation.

I've been through the internet and tried a lot of code, but none of them work the way I need to. I plan to make a hidden field with a random number and send it to the email and at the same time to the php file where the number should appear. Unfortunately, all my attempts to display the value in the email have failed. I use the Contact form 7 plugin. Can you please suggest me some function code that I can add to the functions.php file?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your question would be better if you showed what you've tried, rather than just asking for someone to give you a solution.  You should consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and rewriting your question to include some coding you've tried to show that you have put in a little effort before you came here.

Answer (score 1):

In contact form 7 you can add this :

> [hidden random-field "RANDOM_NUM"]

and in the function file you can add below filter:

```
// define the wpcf7_form_elements callback 
add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_elements', 'filter_wpcf7_form_elements', 10, 1 ); 
function filter_wpcf7_form_elements( $form ) { 
    $rand_num = rand(); //generates rand number
    $form = str_replace( 'RANDOM_NUM', $rand_num, $form );
    return $form;
};
```

Hope the above steps works for you.

Comment: Good job, thank you so much. that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @JosefVolný if that satisfied your need then you can also accept this answer for others reference as well. Thanks